# CKeditor and Input Formats confusion

Tags: wysiwyg

Why is there a 'Security Filters' section within the CKEditor configuration settings?

My understanding is that this is all set within the normal Drupal input formats section (admin/settings/filters). Do the CKEditor input configs replace this when the editor is present in a field?

:-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for posting link answer but, there is a complete tutorial [here](http://wysiwyg.jenlampton.com/).

Comment: OK cool, cheers.

Comment: So basically they both run together, sweet.